# How to know if my question is a dupe if the OP used a different title?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491593/how-to-fix-this-spotify-error) is dupe to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491620/sudo-apt-get-update-fails-with-the-following-messages/491607#491607). *(I was the first user to flag my question as dupe.)* Mods decided to mark it a dupe to another question, that's none of my business. Basically reading [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491620/sudo-apt-get-update-fails-with-the-following-messages/491607#491607) would help me solve my problem.

But how to reach it? My question has a totally different title, therefore it wasn't shown in the suggested list. I can't just go brainstorming, thinking of different titles until I nail it :)

It didn't [even popup on google](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=Problem%20with%20MergeList%20/var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_%20dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-en%255fUS&spell=1&sa=X&ei=fS63U8y2DNOP0wW8goCoCA&ved=0CBsQBSgA&biw=1366&bih=616), and I am an avid googler. Moreover if you use this error message

```
Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS
```

And you just put it in the askubuntu search bar, it would return [this list](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Problem%20with%20MergeList%20%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fapt%2Flists%2Frepository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-en%255fUS). Both Google and SE search engine may contain links to questions similar to mine (like the one you marked my question a dupe to); but I was specifically asking about spotify, I didn't want to go try random solutions, and as it turns  out, Spotify repo is bad, just had to remove it, no further answers or explanations are needed.

I like to know just enough to fix a specific problem, otherwise I would have used arch reading endless docs, learning solutions to problems I may never have!

I never reached the duplicate that I was looking for, although I used the most specific method, searching for the error itself rather than random keywords. Who's to blame me or SE? And what can we do about it?

I decided to ask this question because many of my questions are marked duped on many SE sites, though I really tried to find those dupes but couldn't. Sometimes the user use a different way to ask a question, making it impossible to find it, at least for me anyhow.

Answer (score -1):

## The question didn't show up when you tried to search the logical keywords? Why didn't you edit it‽

And yes, both *your question* and the question that solved your issue titles sucks. "How to fix this spotify error" implies the error is thrown by Spotify client... is not even close. "Sudo apt-get update fails with the following messages" why didn't he just wrote the message, nor anybody else wrote a less sucky title? But well, I tried to explain several times that we need to improve our general quality, but nobody listens so these problems are bound to happen.

I fixed the canonical title at the very least for this particular issue, I will not vote to reopen because my vote will be thrown to the oblivion since nobody will agree.

This is one of those cases where the "canonical" doesn't account for all possible reasons, which in this case is an actual bug in the Spotify repositories hence it can only be fixed by Spotify or you have to live without the repository on your repository list. The case is specific enough (single repository, reproducible always, **canonical solutions will not work**) to not be a duplicate of the canonical question, but meh, nobody listen to the guy with the most answers and score on the relevant tags.

Related:

- [How should questions about compiler errors be titled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102027/213575)
- [Should I write the error message as title of my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230267/213575)

Comment: yes my title do suck but I felt a little awkward using this as a title `Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS`.  thinking of a different title won't work, he's talking about localization and I don't know what! I don't even know what `Sudo apt-get update fails with the following messages` means, it got nothing to do with spotify. My title is wrong but it is short, clear and explains the subject (spotify), I would have never find his question, we use very different keywords.

Comment: @Fischer "The thing that you are asking about should go in the title. If you're asking how to resolve an error message, **the error message should go in the title**." you didn't put the error in the title, heck, your title is even misleading. [This is the general guidance about the topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230273/213575).

Comment: The error has already been fixed by spotify, so I heard.